# Data Back Up Switch View Controller IOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, viewcontroller

I have multiple .xib files and multiple view controllers.

Problem is when I pass  data to parent View Controller from a Subview, Data is successfully passed. But when i switch to another Subview and come back to parent view controller data that has been passed loss.

I keep passed data in an NSMutablearray, so How should I back up passed data that it wont loss when i switch views?

ForStand Button is the NSMutablearray that keeps incoming data from the subview and as seen below it turns to null when i switch to another subview and come back to main view.

Here is the example output:

```
2012-03-06 13:44:38.184 Avicii[726:b603] ForStand Button = '(null)' 
server did not accept client registration 68
2012-03-06 13:44:41.809 Avicii[726:b603] StandLocations (
    "Point Stand",
    "Near Stand"
) 
2012-03-06 13:44:43.252 Avicii[726:b603] ForStand Button = 'Near Stand' 
server did not accept client registration 68
2012-03-06 13:44:56.984 Avicii[726:b603] ForStand Button = '(null)' 
server did not accept client registration 68
```

in Subview  data passes as following:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    StartHuntViewController *startHuntController = [[StartHuntViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartHuntView" bundle:nil];
    startHuntController.forStandButton = [stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    startHuntController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:startHuntController animated:YES];;

   // startHuntController.standLocation.text=[stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [startHuntController release];
    startHuntController =nil;
}
```

In parent ForStand is initilazed as following

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *forStandButton;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize forStandButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent view controller data variables might be getting released in case of memory consumptions...

I will suggest creating the variables in `Appdelegate` and setting it using the

```
[UIApplication shared application] delegate]
```

or **making a new singleton class only to store this data..**

Comment: making a new singleton class it is